# three object as one?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Coming to an issue where I am return three json objects. By all means, All I want to do is to return as one JSON object. Similar to my result down below. So, I am trying to show my controller - I believe its in my controller that is returning 3 objects instead of one. Thanks for the help.

Here is my code:

I tried doing this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "all", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody
    MyAutoComplete getMoney(@RequestParam(value = "myautocomplete") String myautocompleteValue) {

    List<MyAutoComplete> list = myautoCompleteService.gettingMoney(myautocompleteValue);
    return merge(list);

}


MyAutoComplete merge(List<MyAutoComplete> list){
    MyAutoComplete accountacy = list.get(0);
    for (int i = 1; i < list.size(); i++) {
        MyAutoComplete myautoComplete = list.get(i);
        if (myautoComplete.getTimeAnnual() != null) {
            accountacy.setTimeAnnual((autoComplete.getTimeAnnual(());
        }
        if (autoComplete.getTimeBiweekly() != null) {
            accountacy.setTimeBiweekly(autoComplete.getTimeBiweekly());
        }
        if (autoComplete.getTimeHourly() != null) {
            accountacy.setTimeHourly(autoComplete.getTimeHourly());
        }

    }
    return accountacy;
}
```

Comment: Your source code found here https://github.com/va-developer/AutoCompleteAPI is up to date? How did you bind this properties (Hourly, Biweekly, Annual) to your first case JSON?

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot change the query on repository side, you can merge the objects in list to single one in the controller

```
public @ResponseBody
LIst<AutoComplete> getSalary(@RequestParam(value = "autocomplete") String autocompleteValue) {

  List<AutoComplete> list = autoCompleteService.retrieveSalary(autocompleteValue);
  return Arrays.asList(merge(list));

}


AutoComplete merge(List<AutoComplete> list){
    AutoComplete acc = list.get(0);
    for (int i = 1; i < list.size(); i++) {
        AutoComplete autoComplete = list.get(i);
        if (autoComplete.getAnnual() != null) {
            acc.setAnnual(autoComplete.getAnnual());
        }
        if (autoComplete.getBiweekly() != null) {
            acc.setBiweekly(autoComplete.getBiweekly());
        }
        if (autoComplete.getHourly() != null) {
            acc.setHourly(autoComplete.getHourly());
        }

    }
    return acc;
}
```

Comment: @sidgate isnt this line `AutoComplete acc = list.get(0);` just gets only the first row? How can I get my biweekly, and annually data as well to shown in json format?!

Comment: Your question mentions that you want to group all in single result

Comment: no. I show an example. please check `I want to return like this:` schema in my question. thank you!

Comment: and what are you getting now?

Comment: just hourly which is index 0. (first row in db)

Answer (score 0):

I just see your code in github,but the key code is not exist.Now I will say what i guess.
Problem may happen in this code.

```
  @Repository
public interface AutoCompleteRepository extends CrudRepository<AutoComplete, String> {


  @Query("select e from AutoComplete e where e.jobClassCd like %:jobClassCd%")
  public Stream<AutoComplete> streamAll();


  List<AutoComplete> findByJobClassCdStartsWith(String jobClassCd);

}
```

In method fingByJobClassCdStartsWith(String jobClassCd),I think when you query from 
the database,you get three records and you can merge it into one object manually.

Or 
you can put the invisible code here by edit your question.

Comment: yes that is right. I get three records.  So, by using `Stream` it will make it to work?

Comment: You say  Hourly, Biweekly, Annual are the values of of a column called rate_type.If you can make some change  in your sql statements,it will works.Just like group_concat(rate_type)  as rate_type ... group by id can make one record easily,and others are the same.

Comment: can you show me with my `@Query` statement, of how `group_concat(rate_type)` will work? and So, your saying using streams instead?

Comment: I say if you can modify the query sql and change the counts of return records,ohters will do not need to change.e.g.  `select e,group_concat(rate_type) as rate_type from AutoComplete e where e.jobClassCd like %:jobClassCd% group by id` will return one record group by id or other unique field you use.

Comment: If you can't do like this.You can make some code to remove the duplicate and merge it into one obejct in your service code.